# JAXB compile error, unused parameters for afterUnmarshall

Tags: eclipse, compiler-construction, jaxb, javadoc, java-compiler-api

I'm using `void afterUnmarshal(Unmarshaller unmarshaller, Object parent)` in my beans and have got the complier set to fail if parameters are not used.

The compiler seems to be okay with unused parameters if I override a superclass/interface that has a javadoc for the param.

But I can't find any class to override the afterUnmarshall method. Is there no unmarshaller interface or something like it to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not interface provided with the JAXB APIs.  We designed it this way so that you could add just one of `afterUnmarsal` or `beforeUnmarshal` if you wanted.  You could solve this issue by introducing your own interface:

```
package com.example;

public interface UnmarshallerListener {

    void afterUnmarshal(Unmarshaller unmarshaller, Object parent);

}
```